# confused about LINQ to SQL supports only one-to-one mapping of entities to tables

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am little bit confused about this statement that I read in a book

> LINQ to SQL supports only one-to-one mapping of entities to tables.

Does this mean I cannot join tables using Linq to Sql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can definitely do that.  It just means that one entity (aka class in your code) maps to one database table, and vice versa.